# Htmlkit swift query between CSS Parse elements

Tags: html, css, swift, css-selectors

```
span>12:23</span>PM          </dd>\n
```

Hi does anyone know how to get hold of "PM"
after the span - using HTLMKit Cocoapod in swift

```
let AMPM: [String] = document.querySelectorAll("span").compactMap({element in
                guard let span = element.querySelector("dd") else {
                    return nil
                }
```

I've tried the above

Comment: Hi Iska, Yes, thank you :) I made multiple posts